# D3 arc - cornerRadius glitches when near 360 degrees

Tags: d3.js, svg

I managed to create an animated arc with rounded corners, but there is a bug which occurs only when using rounded corners.

Removing the transition doesn't make a difference.

Left is bugged at 351 degrees, right is correct at 350 degrees.

[image][image]

[CODEPEN here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYXwwB?editors=101)

```
var angle = 350; // Change to 351 to see the bug
var width = 150;
var height = 150;
var innerRadius = width / 2 * 0.85;
var outerRadius = width / 2;
var color = '#45C600';
var colorBackground = '#EFEFEF';

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .cornerRadius(20)
  .startAngle(0);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

var background = svg.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: 360 * (Math.PI) / 180
  })
  .style("fill", colorBackground)
  .attr("d", arc);

var foreground = svg.append("path")
  .datum({
    endAngle: (Math.PI) / 180
  })
  .style("fill", color)
  .attr("d", arc);

foreground.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(arcTween, angle * (Math.PI) / 180);

function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {
  transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

    return function(t) {
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      return arc(d);
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it and I'm posting this answer for anyone who encounters that bug in the future and it's not fixed yet.

It turns out, it's a bug in d3.js:

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2249)

SOLUTION:

Download the unminified version of d3.js: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/d3/master/d3.js

Lines 7989-8003 should look like this:

```
      if (rc === rc1) {
        path.push("M", t30[0], "A", rc1, ",", rc1, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t30[1], "A", r1, ",", r1, " 0 ", 1 - cw ^ d3_svg_arcSweep(t30[1][0], t30[1][1], t12[1][0], t12[1][1]), ",", cw, " ", t12[1], "A", rc1, ",", rc1, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t12[0]);
      } else {
        path.push("M", t30[0], "A", rc1, ",", rc1, " 0 1,", cr, " ", t12[0]);
      }
    } else {
      path.push("M", x0, ",", y0);
    }
    if (x3 != null) {
      var rc0 = Math.min(rc, (r0 - lc) / (kc - 1)), t03 = d3_svg_arcCornerTangents([ x0, y0 ], [ x3, y3 ], r0, -rc0, cw), t21 = d3_svg_arcCornerTangents([ x2, y2 ], x1 == null ? [ x0, y0 ] : [ x1, y1 ], r0, -rc0, cw);
      if (rc === rc0) {
        path.push("L", t21[0], "A", rc0, ",", rc0, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t21[1], "A", r0, ",", r0, " 0 ", cw ^ d3_svg_arcSweep(t21[1][0], t21[1][1], t03[1][0], t03[1][1]), ",", 1 - cw, " ", t03[1], "A", rc0, ",", rc0, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t03[0]);
      } else {
        path.push("L", t21[0], "A", rc0, ",", rc0, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t03[0]);
      }
```

Comment out lines 7989, 7991, 7992, 7993, 7999, 8001, 8002 and 8003

This is how it should look like:

```
    //   if (rc === rc1) {
        path.push("M", t30[0], "A", rc1, ",", rc1, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t30[1], "A", r1, ",", r1, " 0 ", 1 - cw ^ d3_svg_arcSweep(t30[1][0], t30[1][1], t12[1][0], t12[1][1]), ",", cw, " ", t12[1], "A", rc1, ",", rc1, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t12[0]);
    //   } else {
    //     path.push("M", t30[0], "A", rc1, ",", rc1, " 0 1,", cr, " ", t12[0]);
    //   }
    } else {
      path.push("M", x0, ",", y0);
    }
    if (x3 != null) {
      var rc0 = Math.min(rc, (r0 - lc) / (kc - 1)), t03 = d3_svg_arcCornerTangents([ x0, y0 ], [ x3, y3 ], r0, -rc0, cw), t21 = d3_svg_arcCornerTangents([ x2, y2 ], x1 == null ? [ x0, y0 ] : [ x1, y1 ], r0, -rc0, cw);
    //   if (rc === rc0) {
        path.push("L", t21[0], "A", rc0, ",", rc0, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t21[1], "A", r0, ",", r0, " 0 ", cw ^ d3_svg_arcSweep(t21[1][0], t21[1][1], t03[1][0], t03[1][1]), ",", 1 - cw, " ", t03[1], "A", rc0, ",", rc0, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t03[0]);
    //   } else {
    //     path.push("L", t21[0], "A", rc0, ",", rc0, " 0 0,", cr, " ", t03[0]);
    //   }
```